# Android countdown timer not getting refreshed if no user activity for some time

Tags: android, textview, countdowntimer, uirefreshcontrol

I've implemented Android Countdown Timer for my app. Its working perfectly. But if I leave screen for 2 minutes(No user activity), timer text does not update. If I restart activity again, it adjusts time elapsed. So Countdown timer is working fine, but text is not getting updated. Anybody any ides ??

Comment: Once you Activity will be destroyed everything will be reseted. You need to make service and then when activity starts again you have to update it from service.